# Excel function query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Problem : I have made some risk amount provisions in excel sheet and those provisions are made for more than 60 stores. Now I would like a function that retrieved today's date from Excel and if the date has passed , the provision column for that specific date should be Zero automatically and apply to all stores.

PS: I'm Excel basic user; any solutions would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1492361/edit) to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

As a "basic user" there are probably thousands of things you are not aware of yet. I've used it 30 years and there's more I don't know, and know I don't, than I do know.

One of them might be a date related function called `TODAY()` which gives you today's date. With it, you can test (compare) the date for a provision against today's date by just using an `IF()` test.

(Say you have the dates for the provisions in column A and the provision amounts in column B. So `A1` has a date and `B1` has the provision that is good through that date.)

In column C (cell `C1` in this example) you could have this formula:

```
=IF( A1 < TODAY(), 0, B1 )
```

It will test the date in A1 against today's date and if it is before today then it puts a 0 in cell `C1` but if it has not passed yet, it puts the provision amount in cell `C1`.

Then, instead of looking down the dates with, perhaps, `VLOOKUP()` and getting the value entered in `B1`, you get the value in `C1` instead.

Do this wherever the provision amounts are. If they are all in a massive table with date and provision columns for each of the 60 stores, then you add a third column to each set and use the above formula.

(Now 60 stores... more in the future? Thinking about that and how you might want a different layout is one of the things the person in the other question meant by changing your data layout.)

Hopefully this is a good guess at what you meant in the question. If so, it's a good, basic solution. If it wasn't, maybe it will give you some inspiration about how to better explain your need.